# How to solve unserialize(): Error at offset 141 of 1423 bytes in laravel?

Tags: php, serialization

this is giving me error when I'm trying to unserialize

this the error

> unserialize(): Error at offset 141 of 1423 bytes

```
'a:8:{i:0;a:4:{s:1:"n";s:10:"Essentials";s:2:"dn";s:17:"Essentials Module";s:1:"u";s:53:"";s:1:"d";s:49:"Essentials features for every growing businesses.";}i:1;a:4:{s:1:"n";s:10:"Superadmin";s:2:"dn";s:17:"Superadmin Module";s:1:"u";s:54:"";s:1:"d";s:76:"Turn your POS to SaaS application and start earning by selling subscriptions";}i:2;a:4:{s:1:"n";s:11:"Woocommerce";s:2:"dn";s:18:"Woocommerce Module";s:1:"u";s:55:"";s:1:"d";s:36:"Sync your Woocommerce store with POS";}i:3;a:4:{s:1:"n";s:13:"Manufacturing";s:2:"dn";s:20:"Manufacturing Module";s:1:"u";s:57:"";s:1:"d";s:70:"Manufacture products from raw materials, organise recipe & ingredients";}i:4;a:4:{s:1:"n";s:7:"Project";s:2:"dn";s:14:"Project Module";s:1:"u";s:51:"";s:1:"d";s:66:"Manage Projects, tasks, tasks time logs, activities and much more.";}i:5;a:4:{s:1:"n";s:6:"Repair";s:2:"dn";s:13:"Repair Module";s:1:"u";s:50:"";s:1:"d";s:248:"Repair module helps with complete repair service management of electronic goods like Cellphone, Computers, Desktops, Tablets, Television, Watch, Wireless devices, Printers, Electronic instruments and many more similar devices which you can imagine!";}i:6;a:4:{s:1:"n";s:3:"Crm";s:2:"dn";s:10:"CRM Module";s:1:"u";s:63:"";s:1:"d";s:39:"Customer relationship management module";}i:7;a:4:{s:1:"n";s:16:"ProductCatalogue";s:2:"dn";s:16:"ProductCatalogue";s:1:"u";s:90:"";s:1:"d";s:32:"Digital Product catalogue Module";}}'
```

Comment: Did someone try to modify this data by hand? It is broken in a way that should not happen as a direct result of `serialize`.

Comment: specifically, `s:53:""` would never happen - it says there is upcoming a 53-character string, and then a string of zero length is given. I didn't measure, but I bet 53 characters after that is offset 141. Fixing that one error was not sufficient, however. You will need to restore that data by creating the data in php and using `serialize()` to put it back in your database.